Query elasticseatrch with pyspark and nested fields
I am trying to query with pyspark an index with documents:
{
    "field1": "field1_data",
    "field2": [
    {
        "field2_1": "x1",
        "field2_2": "x2"
    },
    {
        "field2_1": "x3",
        "field2_2": "x4"
    }
    ]
}


if i query from kibana:
post my_index/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [],
            "filter": [
                "terms" {
                    "field2.field2_1": "x1"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "_source" = ["field1", "field2.field2_1"]
}

it retruns everyting fine:
hits = 
{
    "field1": "field1_data",
    "field2": [
    {
        "field2_1": "x1"
    }
    ]
        
}

now i try to use pyspark:
the data frame schema is:
index1_schema = StructType([
    StructField("field1", StringType(), nullable=True),
    StructField("field2", ArrayType(StructType[
            StructField("field2_1", StringType(), nullable=True),
            StructField("field2_2", StringType(), nullable=True)
        ),
        containsNull=False), nullable=True)
])

i create spark options for elastic:
options ={
"es.nodes": ....,
"es.resource": "my_index",
"es.query": '''
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [],
            "filter": [
                "terms" {
                    "field2.field2_1": "x1"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "_source":["field1", "field2.field2_1"]
    }
    '''
]

i create a data frame reader
reader = sparkSession.read.schema(index1_schema).format('org.elasticsearch.spark.sql').options(options)
than i do 

df = reader.load().select(['field1', 'field2']

the df looks like:
field1             |  field2
=======================
"field1_data" | [{Null, Null}]

where field2 contains an array of pyspark rows with one row object :
{
    "field2_1":None
}


what am i doing wrong?
I tried using different mappings and it did not work

anyone? please help
